# JPQL para consultar data/hora do banco com hibernate sem native query

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa

Existe uma maneira de consultar da data/hora do banco de dados sem usar *ative query*?

No Oracle eu faço isso:

```
 SQLQuery qry = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual");
```

Porém gostaria de uma consulta genérica para não ficar preço ao banco de dados.

Comment: Você precisa usar o sysdate mesmo? Não pode pegar a data usando `new Date()`, ou `Calendar.getInstance();`? Porque aí você realmente não ficaria preso ao banco.

Comment: Sim amigo, preciso tentar recuperar do bando de dados a data.

Answer (score 1):

Tente essa query:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT CURRENT_DATE");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas essa query é nativa e funciona para postgres e talvez para mysql, mas não no Oracle. Procuro uma consulta JPQL em vez de native query

Comment: @DemysCota Na verdade existe isso no JPA, mas ao que parece somente pode ser usado em comparações. [Veja o site do uauHebert](http://uaihebert.com/jpa-consultas-e-dicas/6/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela comentário, pelo que vi vou ter que me contentar com a native query mesmo.